# Receive-Job has different output than a direct command

Tags: powershell, scripting, jira

I've been using this command in my script

```
$jira = Get-JiraIssue -Query $jiraQuery -Credential $jiraCred | Select-Object Assignee,customfield
```

Which results in an array as such:

```
Assignee           customfield
----                 ----
Unassigned         D00525FFKSAN0
first.last       1FLSALF05
```

However, if I run the same command in Start-Job scriptblock:

```
Start-Job -Name Jira -ScriptBlock {param($jiraQuery,$jiraCred) Get-JiraIssue -Query $jiraQuery -Credential $jiraCred | Select-Object Assignee,customfield} -ArgumentList $jiraQuery, $jiraCred

Receive-Job -Name JIra -Keep
```

The results end up being like:

```
Assignee          : Unassigned
customfield          : ASLFDSGLDMF06
RunspaceId          : a670925b-537a-4d54-adce-89c693f3fa9d 
--------    
Assignee          : @{TimeZone=America/Los_Angeles; Key=JIRAUSER0000; AvatarUrl=; Groups=; Active=True; AccountId=; DisplayName=First Last; EmailAddress=first.last@jira.com; Locale=; RestUrl=https://jira.com/rest/api/2/user?username=first.last; Name=first.last}
customfield          : ASLFDSGLDMF05
RunspaceId          : a670925b-537a-4d54-adce-89c693f3fa10d
```

I've tried using -ExpandProperty on the job results, but then the Assignee property takes over and results in:

```
Name                 DisplayName                          Active
----                 -----------                          ------
first.last           First Last                           Yes
first.last2          First Last 2                           Yes
first.last3          First Last 3                           Yes
```

What's happening here? I can't seem to figure out how to get the same results I'm getting by running the command directly, outside of Start-Job

Comment: The issue is that PowerShell tags an extra property when ran in another thread. So select the objects outside of the job(s). `Start-Job {...} | Receive-Job | Select ...`

Comment: Probably some custom formatting view on the objects that are received directly from the cmdlet that is lost when going through Start-Job

Comment: @Daniel you called it. Thank you for your help! Much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Get-JiraIssue` has a custom formatting view which is lost during [serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_output?view=powershell-7.2#deserialized-objects) as [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11954025/daniel) states in his on point comment.

To get around this, and assuming you're looking for the `.Name` property of the nested object in the `Assignee` property here is how you can recreate the object:

```
$job = Start-Job -Name Jira -ScriptBlock {
    param($jiraQuery, $jiraCred)

    Get-JiraIssue -Query $jiraQuery -Credential $jiraCred
} -ArgumentList $jiraQuery, $jiraCred

Receive-Job $job -Keep | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Assignee    = ($_.Assignee, $_.Assignee.Name)[[bool] $_.Assignee.Name]
        customfield = $_.customfield
    }
}
```